# Add Java support to Eclipse

Tags: java, php, eclipse

I have downloaded and installed Eclipse for PHP Developers from here:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

I also need to write some Java applications. How can I add Java support to my PHP Eclipse version? Do I have to install second Eclipse for Java?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should be able to install the JAVA components, using `Help > Install New Software`.

In the list of components, there should be `Programming Languages > Eclipse Java Development Tools`.

Here's a screenshot :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/so-5662465.png))</sub>

Comment: where it the screenshot ?

Comment: In the last version of Eclipse, in the list  "work with" I choose the link of my Eclipse release looks like : **2018-12 - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12** and I entered  **Eclipse Java Development Tools**  as filter key word.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is so trivial to have multiple Eclipse instances, I do just that to seperate php and java environments. This reduces the plugins loaded and you can somewhat keep Eclipse lean. Of course the choice is totally yours.

Answer (score 2):

On my version of eclipse:

Help menu->install new software

Choose the download page for your version of eclipse

There is a category "programming language" which should have Java.

Comment: Exact plugin name is "Eclipse Java Development Tools", so don't search for "Java" as it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

What you downloaded was basically the eclipse core project and a list of standard "addon" packages that might help in PHP development. According tho this [comparison chart](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) you're only missing two packages to now make eclipse ready for java development:

- [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/)
- [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/)

You could just download those two packages from eclipse by going to

> Help->Install new software

to have the standard "Eclipse for Java Development" setup.

Comment: Actually, you really only need JDT. GEF (Graphical Editor Framework) is only necessary if you want a graphical GUI designer for SWT (which you don't need if you write server apps, web apps or Swing apps).

Comment: @sleske Agreed. I was just pointing out what else would be needed to mimic the "Eclipse for Java Developers" package that you can download

Comment: Well, at least the Eclipse package offered for download as "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" on the Eclipse site does not contain GEF.

Comment: @sleske Not according to the comparsion link I provided in my answer?

Comment: That's true... strange. On the download page, you can get a list of components for each package by clicking "Details", there GEF is not listed for "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". Also, I just downloaded the Linux version, and it came without GEF. Maybe the comparison page is outdated...